# How to setup CSV file in the db/migration folder?

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, data-migration

In usual migration I am using SQL usual `COPY CSV` command, but now all the SpringBoot project must be into a `git` and generic path for clone (and do it in a protected server):

- where the best place or "standard Spring folder" to CSV files used by `main/resources/db/migration`?
- how to use the `COPY` (SQL) with a *relative path*?

---

Relative path by shell is:

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres gcp -c    "\
  CREATE TABLE question_import (question text, weight integer); \
  COPY question_import FROM STDIN WITH CSV HEADER delimiter as ',' \
"    < _docs/data/csc-questoes.csv
```

but PostgreSQL not supports internal *relative path*.

Comment: But you will use psql in any case? Or another client?

Comment: @TommasoDiBucchianico Hum... Ideal is to use "only `db/migration`", independent of other server-side intalls

Answer (score 1):

Once you're using SpringBoot, why not incorporating the benefits of [Liquibase](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html) (section 75.5.2)?

Apart from the ability to define/version your database schema, there are also methods for loading data, e.g. CSV in your case:

```
<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="loadUpdateData-example">
<loadUpdateData catalogName="cat"
        encoding="UTF-8"
        file="com/example/users.csv"
        primaryKey="pk_id"
        quotchar="A String"
        schemaName="public"
        separator="A String"
        tableName="person">
    <column name="address" type="varchar(255)"/>
</loadUpdateData>
```

The [Spring-Boot-Liquibase Sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-liquibase) project should give you a quickstart.